# sql sales data grouped by year in separate columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have two input tables:

- analysis (an_id, an_name, an_cost, an_price, an_group)
- orders (ord_id, ord_datetime, ord_an) # orders of analysis (sales)

For every analysis_id I need to show the amount of orders for years 2020 and 2019.

Expected output:

| an | year2019 | year2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 | 41 |
| 2 | 29 | 28 |
| 3 | 42 | 37 |
| 4 | 26 | 35 |
| 5 | 32 | 34 |

logic in my query:

- step1 - get orders table data only for years 2019,2020 - use CTE and extract()
- step2 - aggregate by year

My query:

```
WITH helper AS (
    SELECT an_id, 
           ord_id, 
           EXTRACT(year from ord_datetime) as year
    FROM analysis a 
    INNER JOIN orders o ON o.ord_an = a.an_id
    WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM ord_datetime) in (2019.0,2020.0)
)
SELECT an_id, 
       CASE WHEN year = 2019.0 THEN COUNT(ord_id) ELSE 0 END AS year2019,
       CASE WHEN year = 2020.0 THEN COUNT(ord_id) ELSE 0 END AS year2020
FROM helper  
GROUP BY year, an_id
ORDER BY an_id
```

The current output of my query:

| an_id | year2019 | year2020 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 41 |
| 2 | 29 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 28 |
| 3 | 42 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in your query may be inside your `GROUP BY` clause, because you're grouping on the year too. Instead consider the following approach, where you invert the position of the `COUNT` aggregate function and the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT a.an_id,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM o.ord_datetime) = 2019 THEN o.ord_id END) AS year2019,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(year FROM o.ord_datetime) = 2020 THEN o.ord_id END) AS year2020
FROM       analysis a
INNER JOIN orders o
        ON o.ord_an = a.an_id
GROUP BY a.an_id
```

**Note**: the `ELSE` part of your `CASE` statement is not necessary, as long as values will be defaulted to NULL (and not counted in by the `COUNT`).